# React native: Islamic/Hijri date to Gregorian date only available from Hijri 1355H

Tags: reactjs, react-native, calendar, momentjs, hijri

I have done some research but the only packages I have found provide conversions from 1355 to date.
Also tried using this api `https://api.aladhan.com/v1/hToG/2-03-1436`
But this returns 30 days for all the months which I think is not correct.

Is there a library or an API I can use which can give me 150 years of accurate conversions?

These did not work for me

`moment-hijri`
`hijri-date`
`hijrah-date`

Comment: `@umalqura/core` this one maps 126 years

Comment: Please leave an example you want to convert. I think I can help you.